# How to identify custom keywords of sentence and assign custom names in new column?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm new to the NLP NER (named-entity recognition) world (and programming in general) and am looking for some guidance with starting/knowing how to complete a project.

I have an excel file with about 5 columns of multiple sentences in each row (about 15000 rows). Each row has several paragraphs of words from people filling out a survey.

I want to iterate through each row to identify several certain words, like "hot", "cold", "lukewarm", "ball", "paper", etc.

If any of these words are found in a sentence, I want to create a new word in a new column next to it to represent it - for example, words like "hot", "cold", and "lukewarm" found in the sentences would be given a new word like "temperature" in a new column; "ball" or "bat" would be given a new word "toy" in a new column; "paper" would be given a new word "supply" in a new column, and so on.

In addition, if there is more than one word found in each sentence, each new word would be inserted in the new cell/column separated by a comma. So if "hot", "ball", and "paper" were all in the same sentence, the new column would have `"temperature","toy","supply"`. So basically, I don't want to remove any words from the sentences - I want to add new tags/words in a new column next to them.

I need to do this in Python. So far I've been looking using at spacy.io, nltk, and StanfordNERTagger, but if there's a simpler way, that would be great too. There is some stuff/example online such as https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2F2290fc65-0041-4c87-a898-0289f59aa8ba and https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities but to be honest, I'm not sure where to start so I am looking for some direction. Here are some examples but how do I customize this to specific tags and keywords that I need?

```
!pip install -U spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
import random
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
nlp = spacy.load('en')
TEST_DATA, _ = load_data_spacy("data/test.txt")

    test_sentences = [x[0] for x in TEST_DATA[0:15]] # extract the sentences from [sentence, entity]
    for x in test_sentences:
        doc = nlp(x)
        displacy.render(doc, jupyter = True, style = "ent")
    warnings.filterwarnings("default")

def timer(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        print("Completed in {} seconds".format(int(te - ts)))
        return result
    return timed

# Data must be of the form (sentence, {entities: [start, end, label]})
@timer
def train_spacy(train_data, labels, iterations, dropout = 0.2, display_freq = 1):
    ''' Train a spacy NER model, which can be queried against with test data
   
    train_data : training data in the format of (sentence, {entities: [(start, end, label)]})
    labels : a list of unique annotations
    iterations : number of training iterations
    dropout : dropout proportion for training
    display_freq : number of epochs between logging losses to console
    '''
    nlp = spacy.blank('en')
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
   
    # Add entity labels to the NER pipeline
    for i in labels:
        ner.add_label(i)

    # Disable other pipelines in SpaCy to only train NER
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
        nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_model' # without this, spaCy throws an "unnamed" error
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itr in range(iterations):
            random.shuffle(train_data) # shuffle the training data before each iteration
            losses = {}
            batches = minibatch(train_data, size = compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(          
                    texts,
                    annotations,
                    drop = dropout,  
                    sgd = optimizer,
                    losses = losses)
            if itr % display_freq == 0:
                print("Iteration {} Loss: {}".format(itr + 1, losses))
    return nlp

# Train (and save) the NER model
ner = train_spacy(TRAIN_DATA, LABELS,6)
ner.to_disk("models/spacy_example")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of keywords are not very large then you could easily accomplish this task using [wink-nlp](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) and minimal coding in Javascript. Here is the sample code to detect these keywords and map it to the category for each sentence:

```
const winkNLP = require( 'wink-nlp' );
const model = require( 'wink-eng-lite-web-model' );
const its = require( 'wink-nlp/src/its.js' );
const text = 'I was playing with doll when my pen fell down. The weather is warm today.';

const patterns = [
  { name: 'temperature', patterns: [ '[hot|cold|warm]' ] },
  { name: 'toy', patterns: [ '[ball|bat|doll]' ] },
  { name: 'supply', patterns: [ '[pen|pencil|paper]' ] }
];

const nlp = winkNLP( model );
nlp.learnCustomEntities(patterns);

const doc = nlp.readDoc( text );

doc.sentences().each( ( s ) => {
  console.log( `${s.out()}\n${s.customEntities().out( its.detail ).map( ( e ) => e.type ).join( ', ')}\n`);
} );
```

The output:

```
I was playing with doll when my pen fell down.
toy, supply

The weather is warm today.
temperature
```

Documentation and how to's are at https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comment! Would you by chance also know how to do it in Python?

Comment: You could use rule-based matching (https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) of spaCy, which would be very similar to the above approach.

Comment: Do you have the list of word and the replacement you want to put ?